# Is it possible to get this UUID from a random generator?

Tags: uuid

is it possible to get this UUID "00000CB98D9A4C87A6504C5313080EB9" from a random generator ?

Because of the five zeros at the beginning.

Comment: Yes. Assuming a good RNG `00000` is exactly as likely as the leading 5 digits as `12345` is (i.e. incredibly unlikely, but not excluded via anything in the spec). The version and variant encoding in the UUID means that an all-zero UUID should never be generated, but leading `0` are not impossible.